# Solving quasilinear PDE with the Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
x u_x + u_y = x - u \\
u(x,0) = \phi(x)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and using the method of characteristics I get the characteristic ODEs
\begin{equation*}
\dot{x}(s) = x(s), \quad \dot{y}(s) = 1, \quad \dot{z}(s) = x(s) - z(s). 
\end{equation*}
Integrating this system of equations, I get $x(s) = x_0 e^s$, $y(s) = s + y_0 = s$, $z(s) = z_0 e^{-s} + \frac{1}{2} x_0 e^s$. Since $s = y$, $x_0 = x e^{-y}$. We also have $z(0) = \phi(x_0)$, so
\begin{equation*}
\phi(xe^{-y}) = z_0 + \frac{1}{2} x e^{-y}
\end{equation*}
and I get
\begin{equation*}
u(x,y) = u(x(s), y(s)) = z(s) = z(y) = \big{(} \phi(xe^{-y}) - \frac{1}{2}xe^{-y} \big{)} e^{-y} + \frac{1}{2} x. 
\end{equation*}
However, I find that the term $\phi(xe^{-y})e^{-y}$ solves the homogeneous PDE (no $x$ term) and $\frac{1}{2}x$ solves the inhomogeneous PDE, but the term $-\frac{1}{2}xe^{-2y}$ does not work. I am confused as to where I have gone wrong, and any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}xe^{-2y}=\psi(xe^{-y})e^{-y}$ where $\psi(t)=1/2$. So it is part of the solution of the homogeneous PDE as well.

Comment: @Chrystomath I think you mean 'where $\psi(t) = \color{red}t/2$'.

Comment: @mattos Yes!! Thanks.